# how to burn macOS installer to a bootable DVD

Tags: macos, disk-image

I have downloaded
/Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app
I'd like to burn an .iso file I can install in VirtualBox on a newer mac that runs Catalina.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use an `.iso` to install High Sierra. You use a `.vdi` instead.

> I have had problems using any of the version 7 Virtual Box releases when the host is Catalina. This answer was tested using VirtualBox version 6.1.44 on 2013 iMac with macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 installed.

The steps to create the `.vdi` are given below. Here I assume your Install macOS High Sierra application is complete. In other words, the size of the application should be about 5.24 GB.

1. Set the variable `SIZE` to be the size of the disk images to be created, which will contain the High Sierra installer files. Here a value of 16 GiB was chosen. Since both disk images will be dynamically allocated, the actual physical space occupied by each disk image file will be about 5 to 6 GB.

   ```
   SIZE="$((2**34))"
   ```
2. Create a new dynamically allocated disk image containing a JHFS+ formatted volume named `MyVolume`. The image will be stored in the file named `HighSierraInstaller.sparseimage`.

   ```
   hdiutil create -size $SIZE -fs jhfs+ -volname MyVolume -type SPARSE -attach HighSierraInstaller
   ```
3. Set the variable `ID` to the identifier assign to the attached image. This identifier can be set manually after observing the output from the previous step or can be set by entering the commands given below.

   ```
   ID="$(diskutil info MyVolume | grep -i "Part of Whole")"
   ID="${ID##* }"
   ```
4. Write the High Sierra installer files to the volume named `MyVolume`. The volume name will change to `Install macOS High Sierra`.

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
   ```
5. (This step is optional.) VirtualBox has been known to boot to an UEFI shell instead of from the `Install macOS High Sierra` volume. Adding the following `startup.nsh` file will cause an UEFI shell to automatically execute the macOS High Sierra installer boot file.

   ```
   echo -E '\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi' >'/Volumes/Install macOS High Sierra/startup.nsh'
   ```
6. Unmount the volume named `Install macOS High Sierra`.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk $ID
   ```
7. Create the dynamically allocated disk image file `HighSierraInstaller.vdi`. This file is compatible with VirtualBox.

   ```
   dd if=/dev/r$ID bs=1m | VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin HighSierraInstaller.vdi $SIZE
   ```

   The “Oracle® VirtualBox® User Manual Version 7.0.12” states the following:

   > Note: For compatibility with earlier versions of Oracle VM VirtualBox, you can use
   > the `VBoxManage convertdd` command instead of the `VBoxManage convertfromraw`
   > command.
8. Eject the disk image containing the volume named `Install macOS High Sierra`.

   ```
   hdiutil detach $ID
   ```
9. Remove the original disk image file `HighSierraInstaller.sparseimage`.

   ```
   rm HighSierraInstaller.sparseimage
   ```

When finished, edit the VirtualBox settings for the High Sierra virtual machine. Add `HighSierraInstaller.vdi` as a second hard disk. The image below shows the second disk added to the virtual machine named "High Sierra".

[image]

I would also recommend setting the number processors to at least 2 CPUs, as shown below.

[image]

Next, start the virtual machine and install High Sierra. Do not forget to use the Disk Utility to initialize the first drive. If you encounter a display similar to the image shown below, then select the `Cancel` button to proceed with the installation.

[image]

After you are finished installing High Sierra, you can edit the settings and remove the second drive.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Apple will not let you run older than macOS shipped with a Mac.

Command `softwareupdate` in Terminal tells you what macOS version(s) can be downloaded and installed on your Mac:

```
softwareupdate --list-full-installers
```

Source: [How to Download Full MacOS Installers from Command Line](https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/13/how-download-full-macos-installer-terminal/)

Comment: The command `softwareupdate --list-full-installers` does not work with Catalina.

Comment: Often you can run versions of OS X/macOS in a virtual machine as a guest even when the same version will not run on the host Mac. Apple allows Mountain Lion (10.8) through Catalina (10.15) to run on my 2013 iMac. However, I can run Snow Leopard (10.6) through Monterey (12) in various virtual machines as guests.

Comment: OP isn't asking how to download, but [correctly or incorrectly] how to burn to DVD. This doesn't attempt to answer that question, nor even challenge its assumption.